# Finding an Awesome method to Prove a fomular $\sum_{j=0}^n(x_j-x)^kl_j(x)\equiv 0$ for $l_j(x)$ , the Lagrange Interplotion Basis

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Prove a fomular $\sum_{j=0}^n(x_j-x)^kl_j(x)\equiv 0$ for $l_j(x)$ , the Lagrange Interplotion Basis
$$
l_{j}(x)=\frac{\left(x-x_{0}\right) \cdots\left(x-x_{j-1}\right)\left(x-x_{j+1}\right) \cdots\left(x-x_{n}\right)}{\left(x_{j}-x_{0}\right) \cdots\left(x_{j}-x_{j-1}\right)\left(x_{j}-x_{j+1}\right) \cdots\left(x_{j}-x_{n}\right)}
$$
$x_j$ are different points $(j=0,1,2,\cdots,n)$

My works:
I have known the fomular
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n} x_{j}^{k} l_{j}(x) \equiv x^{k}, \quad k=0,1, \cdots, n
$$
I want to prove $\sum_{j=0}^n(x_j-x)^kl_j(x)\equiv 0$

I use the above fomular to get the following for $k = 1,\cdots,n$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{k}\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
l
\end{array}\right) x_{j}^{l}(-x)^{k-l} l_{j}(x) \\
=& \sum_{l=0}^{k}\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
l
\end{array}\right)(-x)^{k-l} \sum_{j=0}^{n} x_{j}^{l} l_{j}(x) \\
=& \sum_{l=0}^{k}\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
l
\end{array}\right)(-x)^{k-l} x^{l} \\
=&\,(x-x)^{k}\\
\equiv & \,0
\end{aligned}
$$
I wonder is there a method doesn't use the above fomular, or can inspire me from a different opinion. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My way:**

If $f(x)$ is a $k$-order polynomial with $0\le k\le n$, it holds that
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n f(x_j)l_j(x) \equiv f(x). $$
So, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we can choose $f_t(x)=(x-t)^k$, then the equality
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n (x_j-t)^k l_j(x) = (x-t)^k $$
holds for every $t$ and $x$.

If $k=1,2,\cdots,n$, let $t=x$, then
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n (x_j-x)^k l_j(x) \equiv 0 $$
follows.

Comment: But the when $k=0$ , that identity is not succeed, you didn't discuss the special case

Comment: oh, yes, I will correct it.